# React native app crashes when some components module are being imported

Tags: ios, typescript, react-native

My index.ts file looks like as following:

```
import StaffMembers from './StaffMembers';
import GuestMembers from './GuestMembers';
export {
  StaffMembers,
  GuestMembers,
};
```

My folder structure looks like
[image]

This is my StaffMembers.tsx file :

```
import React from 'react';
import { AppDivider, CustomLabel } from '.';
import { View } from 'react-native-animatable';
import styles from '../styles';
import { Dropdown, TextInput, Label } from '../../../../components';

const StaffMembers: React.FC<{
  member: string;
  organisation: string;
  orgLabel: string;
  canDelete: () => void;
  errors: any;
  onDelete: () => void;
  onValueUpdate: (updated: any) => void;
  options: any[];
  onDropdownStateChange: () => void;
  zIndex: number;
  onBlur: (fieldName: string) => void;
}> = ({
  member,
  organisation,
  orgLabel,
  canDelete,
  errors = {},
  onDelete = () => {},
  onValueUpdate = () => {},
  options = [],
  zIndex = 1,
  onBlur = () => console.log(),
}) => {
  return (
    <View style={[styles.listItem, { zIndex }]}>
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <Dropdown
          label={
            canDelete ? (
              <CustomLabel
                title={<Label title='Staff Member' required />}
                onDelete={onDelete}
              />
            ) : (
              'Staff Member'
            )
          }
          data={options}
          onSelectItem={item => onValueUpdate({ member: item.value, ...item })}
          errorMessage={errors.member}
          value={member}
          onBlur={() => onBlur('member')}
          required
        />
      </View>

      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <TextInput
          disabled={true}
          label={'Employee ID'}
          value={organisation}
          errorMessage={errors.organisation}
          onChangeText={(val: string) => onValueUpdate({ organisation: val })}
        />
      </View>
      <AppDivider />
    </View>
  );
};

export default StaffMembers;
```

I'm importing components as

```
import { StaffMembers, GuestMembers } from '../request/components';
```

However when my app screen needs to load the component, it crashes giving the below error: [Error when app crashes while loading component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9olO5.png)

When I edit the component's file and save it again, the app works fine.

Is there anything that I'm missing while importing the component? or something else?

Comment: can you please show me your components file ?

Comment: I have edited the question, please check.

Answer (score 0):

The error clearly stat that you are not exporting the component/screen,
You are importing  StaffMembers, GuestMembers which are modules, and not a class or component nested in the file, to solve this:
create `index.js` file in the root directory of ../request/components, and inside `index.js` file:
import StaffMembers from './StaffMembers';
import GuestMembers from './GuestMembers ';

export {
StaffMembers,
GuestMembers
};

now you can import the modules easily as you need.

Comment: Please check my edited question. The folder structure is already in the suggested format.

Comment: Can you please share your code inside StaffMembers.tsx codes?

Comment: Updated question, please check.